# Export signed app hangs

Tags: android, export, apk, adt

I have a problem with exporting signed application. I have done some updates on my application, so I export application like I did before.

```
Right click on project -> Android tools -> Export signed application.
```

When I get to final step (look at the picture on link below) I press Finish. Loading cursor is showed but application does not get exported. I have tried with new keystore too.
I already disabled Automatic builds.
What could be the cause?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2gYE.png]